# How Do i create UIimageView Dynamically (XCODE)

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, dynamic, uiimageview

Hi everybody I making an Xcode App but have now been stuck for 2 days

in my app I have to create some images (which balls) in the amount stated by the user .

e,g if the user says make 10 10 balls should appear on the same screen at random locations I know to make location random but can't figure how to do it ... how do i connect to the interface builder ???

tried this
 1.h
    UIImageView *c[100];

1.m

```
for (int i = 0; i < "users value" ; i++) {
    float x = (float)(67 + ((95 + 22) * i));
    UIImageView *c[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20.0f, 95.0f, 149.0f)];

    [ballsView[i]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    ballsView[i].opaque = YES;        
    ballsView[i].hidden = NO; /* change to YES for distribution */        
    }
```

Comment: Figured It Out for (int i = 0; i < x ; i++,z++)
     {
         UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
         c[i]=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image1];
         c[i].frame=CGRectMake(z*50,450,50,50); 
         [self.view addSubview:c[i]];
     }

Comment: Just put this comment as answer and accept it this will increase your reputation and your acceptance ratio.

Answer (score -1):

use this. hope helps

```
for (int i = 0; i < "users value" ; i++) 
{
    float x = (float)(67 + ((95 + 22) * i));
    UIImageView *c[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20.0f, 95.0f, 149.0f)];
    c[i].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [ballsView[i] addSubView:c[i]];
    ballsView[i].opaque = YES;        
    ballsView[i].hidden = NO; /* change to YES for distribution */        
}
```